# Filter List Data C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, duplicates

How can I convert my list of strings:

```
List<string> appliedFilters = filterString.Split(',').Select(n => n).ToList();
```

Into a list without duplicates?

My list of strings (appliedFilters) looks like this:

```
7-27,
2-37,
7-28,
9-18,
9-22,
9-80
```

I need to output this list without duplicates in the first part of the string, e.g:

```
7-27-28, 2-37, 9-18-22-80
```

I'm sure there's a LINQ query here somewhere, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: You can omit `Select(n => n)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
filterString.Split(',')
  .Select(s => s.Split('-'))
  .GroupBy(ss => ss[0])
  .Select(group => string.Join("-", new[]{group.Key}.Concat(group.Select(ss => ss[1])).ToArray()));
```

Comment: I think this is when elegance vs. readability becomes an issue. It's hard to grasp what's going on in that LINQ for me personally. Upvote anyway for proposing a solution that, on closer inspection, looks like it would work.

Comment: Exactly what I needed & an impressive LINQ query :) Thank you

Comment: @HenkHolterman IEnumerable overload only in .net 4.0 and later